# Make Bike stable in Unity 2D game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing 2D game somewhat like **Hill climb Racing** with the bike and For jointing of Wheel I'm using **Wheel Joint 2D** and for movement, I'm using

```
rb.AddTorque(rotation * rotationSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

[image]

It's working fine but after getting speed Bike is vibrating and Wheel leaves its original joint place.

I'm following this tutorial [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgG9us3QkTE&t)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem with this tutorial and i resolve it by using motor instead **AddTorque**
And if your wheel leaves it's original place. Zoom it and make sure the **Wheel Joint 2D** is perfectly in center of wheel otherwise it will vibrate on place.

For this tutorial I resolve it by using this code for BikeController.

```
using UnityEngine;
public class BikeController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 1500;
    public float rotationSpeed = 10f;
    public WheelJoint2D backWheel;
    public WheelJoint2D frontWheel;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float movement = 0f;
    private float rotation = 0f;
    public Transform player;
    void Update()
    {
        movement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * speed; 
        rotation = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch tch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if (tch.position.x > player.position.x)
            {
                movement = speed;
            }
            if (tch.position.x < player.position.x)
            {
                movement = -speed;
            }
        }
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (movement == 0f)
        {
            backWheel.useMotor = false;
            frontWheel.useMotor = false;
        }
        else
        {
            backWheel.useMotor = true;
            frontWheel.useMotor = true;
            JointMotor2D motor = new JointMotor2D { motorSpeed = movement, maxMotorTorque = 10000 };
            backWheel.motor = motor;
            frontWheel.motor = motor;
        }
        rb.AddTorque(rotation * rotationSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's for mobile and touch device. If any touch detected then this part will execute and detect where exactly touch  your screen and if you touch right side of screen bike will run on that side.